# Dynamic query with union based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a stored procedure which gets data per company and performs a SELECT INTO statement. Currently, I have an if condition, which will only run for selected company. However, after this I have a number of Union statements which union all the tables that were created by SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT * INTO ##LevelAll FROM ##Levela
UNION
SELECT * FROM ##Levelb 
UNION
SELECT * FROM ##Levelc
UNION
SELECT * FROM ##Leveld
UNION
SELECT * FROM ##Levele
```

The problem I am running into is that if I am not running the query for level c then my code above will fail.

Is there a way I can query this dynamically... based on which company I'm running the stored procedure 4? (I can run this for multiple company 'CompanyA,CompanyB,CompanyC).

Comment: What do companies have to do with levels?  Don't tell me that you are storing each company's records in a separate table!  If so, redesign the database.

Comment: Are you creating the temp table also in the condition...what if you declare them outside the if, at the beginning of your stored procedure...

Comment: Then always run the query for level C so this one never fails. You can fill it with nothing (`IF @doC THEN SELECT ... INTO ... FROM; ELSE SELECT TOP(0) ... INTO ... FROM;`, or similar techniques for creating an empty table with the proper schema). If you can avoid a dynamic query by making other code more complicated, it usually still pays off to do so. Per @Gordon however, you may be much better off with a better design up-front so this sort of querying isn't needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

## As has been mentioned in the comments you would really benefit from simply changing your database structure.

But if you can't, you can avoid dynamic SQL and a lot of duplicate code by using a parameterised `top (x) percent` where you specify either `100` or `0` depending on if you want return the data from that part of the `union` or not.

I would also say it looks as if you aren't going to care about duplicates in this query as the 'levels' are different companies, so you can use `union all` instead of `union` which will speed your performance:

```
declare @a int = 100
        ,@b int = 100
        ,@c int = 0     -- No records from table c will be returned.
        ,@d int = 100
        ,@e int = 100;

SELECT TOP (@a) PERCENT * 
INTO ##LevelAll
FROM ##Levela
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (@b) PERCENT * 
FROM ##Levelb
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (@c) PERCENT * 
FROM ##Levelc
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (@d) PERCENT * 
FROM ##Leveld
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (@e) PERCENT * 
FROM ##Levele;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built a dynamic query based on a variable passed through your stored procedure. My text is commented as to what is going on.

First, you need a table-valued function to split your parameter so that each company listed in it is a row in the resulting returned table. Here is a function below, you will need to create this on your database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSplit] 
( 
    @string VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(Item VARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (Item)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Next in the stored procedure, we use this function to split your parameter into rows, into a temporary table called `#Companies`. Then, we use a loop to go through `#Companies` to create your `UNION` queries (or not, if there is only one value). Again, I have heavily commented this as to what I am doing.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspLevelReports
 @param VARCHAR(MAX)

/* Use this for testing your parameters: 
EXEC uspLevelReports @param = 'A,B,D'
 */

AS

BEGIN TRY


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Companies') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #Companies

-- use the split function to put each company into a table, and assign it a row number (necessary for the loop below)
SELECT
Item
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Item ASC) AS RowNo
INTO #Companies
FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@param,',')


-- Select below is for testing so you can see the effect:
-- SELECT * FROM #Companies

-- Create the basic query here, with the company suffix
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) =  'SELECT * From tempdb..##Level'

-- Start to loop through #Companies, for each row no higher than 1, a union will be added
-- First, tell the loop where to start and end:
DECLARE @RowNo INT = 1 -- Your starting RowNo, should always be 1 so won't do a MIN() here
DECLARE @MaxNo INT = ( -- The highest RowNo in #Companies
    SELECT 
    MAX(RowNo)
    FROM #Companies
    )
DECLARE @originalSQL  NVARCHAR(4000) = @sql -- @Sql will be modified in the loop but we still need the original form to keep adding to each union if one is there

WHILE @RowNo <= @MaxNo  -- we will increase the value of @RowNo by 1 each time,the loop will break when @RowNo gets higher than @MaxNo
BEGIN

-- Find the company that corresponds to the @RowNo value in #Companies and add it to a variable:
DECLARE @suffix VARCHAR(100) = (
    SELECT 
    Item 
    FROM #Companies 
    WHERE RowNo = @RowNo)

IF @RowNo = @MaxNo -- If statement for the final Item in #Companies, this stops us adding UNION where we've finished the query
    SET @sql += @suffix
ELSE
    SET @sql += @suffix + ' UNION ' + @originalSQL;

SET @RowNo += 1 -- Add one to move to next RowNo in #Companies

PRINT @sql -- This is for testing so you can see in Messages how the query is being built each loop

END

PRINT 'Final query: ' + @sql  -- This is for testing so you can see in Messages what your final query is



-- Create your level all table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##LevelAll') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE ##LevelAll

-- You need to create your ##LevelAll table with all the columns needed, so amend them with their datatypes below mine is just for example:

CREATE TABLE ##LevelAll(
Company CHAR(1)
,value INT
)
--- insert into your level all table
INSERT INTO ##LevelAll
-- by executing the statement inside your string variable
exec sp_executesql @sql
-- publish the results
SELECT * FROM ##LevelAll

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    -- Your error trapping variables

END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am asking for. Essentially I am trying to perform a Union statement, but if the parameter doesn't have that Company The code is not executed, So I am essentially performing a UNION for table that do not exist as the code perform as SELECT INTO statement for each company.